# Confused about the recursive inner function for factorial calculation

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Confused about the recursive inner function for factorial calculation

```
>>> def factorial(n):
...     def fac_iter(n, accum):
...         if n <= 1:
...             return accum
...         return fac_iter(n - 1, n * accum)
...     return fac_iter(n, 1)
...
>>> factorial(5)
120
```

What I am confused is why there is no `else` before stating `return fac_iter(n - 1, n * accum)`. In my opinion this recursive function `fac_iter` will iterate forever. I tried to add an `else` as my logic:

```
...        if n <= 1:
...            return accum
...        else:
...            return fac_iter(n - 1, n * accum)
>>>    else:
        ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

That's weird. Am I missing something?

Comment: a `return` *exits* the function (cf. the one in the `if` block), so there is no need to follow it with `else`.

Comment: Read the Error: You mixed space and tab and thus have a false indentation. Otherwise your inserted `else` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got is because you mixed tabs and spaces, not because you added `else:`. If you use spaces consistently your addition works:

```
>>> def factorial(n):
...     def fac_iter(n, accum):
...         if n <= 1:
...             return accum
...         else:
...             return fac_iter(n - 1, n * accum)
...     return fac_iter(n, 1)
...
>>> factorial(5)
120
```

The `else` is fine, but is *just not needed*.

When the `if` test is *true*, the next instruction is a `return` statement, which *exits the function*. This means whatever code is on the line after that is *never reached anyway*. In other words, the second `return` line is only ever reached when the `if` test is false, with or without the `else:` block.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, that's exactly what I am confused. Now I understand when the code runs to the `return` also means the end of the this function, like a `break`. Really grateful to you.

Comment: By the way, there is no indentation problem with the `else` statement I insert. I double check. As your suggestion, I think the problem lies in the first `return`, which means the end of the inner function, thus the following `else` can never work in this inner function. So, the indentation problem occurs because python cannot identify if `else` belongs to `fac_iter(n, accum):` or `def factorial(n):`

Comment: @XiongLei: no, you did have an indentation problem. You *mixed tabs and spaces*. The original code block used only spaces, you used a tab somewhere. Python 3 doesn't allow you to do this. The exception given has a very specific meaning, your interpretation is incorrect.

Comment: @XiongLei: You can see from the code in my answer that Python has no issues whatsoever identifying that the `else:` is part of the `if` statement. I only used spaces to create the indentation, however.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I copy and paste into VIM editor. There are some tabs or spaces that I cannot see. Seems need to be careful when using VIM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You start with `n=5` and call `def fac_iter(5, 1)`

this will call `fac_iter(4, 5 * 1)`

this will call `fac_iter(3, 4 * 5 * 1)`

this will call `fac_iter(2, 3 * 4 * 5 * 1)`

this will call `fac_iter(2, 3 * 4 * 5 * 1)`

this will call `fac_iter(1, 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 1)`

this will return `2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 1`

The else is not needed - the n is decreased by 1 all the time, sometime it is going to be 1 and the `if` is true. then the accum is returned until then its calling itself with n thats 1 less then before.

Done.